# reading special characters from docx

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to read a docx file, than split it into the important parts and insert them into my database. The problem is that my docx file is in portuguese, so it has a lot of special characters (e.g. á, ã, â)
and I'm struggling myself to solve this problem for some days already. Because when I add to the database, the special characters turn to '?'.

This is my code:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
document = docx.Document('teste.docx')
docText = '\n\n'.join([paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs])
d2 = docText.decode("utf-8")

N = len(d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n"))

query = ''
questao = {}

for i in range(0,N):
    s = d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i]
    try:
        isinstance(int(s[0:2]), int)
        questao[num_questoes] = d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i][3:len(s)]
        query = 'INSERT INTO multichoice_question (category_id, content) VALUES ("4", "' + d2.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace').split("\n")[i][3:len(s)] + '");'
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            db.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "error %s" %e
            db.rollback()  
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it MySQL database? There is only two problems may be:

1. When creating connection to database you forgotten to set connection charset to utf8, so it tries to write your text as ASCI(which is default in MySQL). Show part where you are establish connection to database.
   If you are using MySQLdb package, then you must add use_unicode=True and charset="utf8" parameters to your MySQLdb.connect function call.
2. You table/columns charset is not UTF8, but one of ASCI charset's. Change it.

Comment: thanks! can you give an example how to do these steps (1 and 2)?

Comment: @user3511563, for #1 - If you are using MySQLdb package, then you must add use_unicode=True and charset="utf8" parameters to your MySQLdb.connect function call.

Comment: @user3511563, for #2 - connect to your database using some GUI-client for MySQL like PhpMyAdmin, Adminer, MySql Workbench. Then check your table/columns dentition - in charset parameter there can be something else than "utf8"